# Hard integral and numeration base problem

Tags: definite-integrals, number-systems

Let $b, c \in \mathbb N$ with $2\le b <c$.

We define the function $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ such that:
\begin{align}
  x = (0.\ a_1 a_2 a_3...)_b &\mapsto f(x) = (0.\ a_1 a_2 a_3...)_c \\
  f(1) &\mapsto 1
\end{align}
where $(0.\ a_1a_2a_3...)_b$ denotes a decimal number in base $b$ (similarly for $c$), that is:
$$
  (0.\ a_1a_2a_3...)_b = \sum_k \frac{a_k}{b^k}
  \qquad
  a_k \in\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}
$$

**Question:** calculate $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx $.

From $b < c$, I deduced that $f(x) < x,\ \forall x \in [0, 1)$, but that's all I have.

Comment: This question needs formatting.

Comment: @Sheljohn I did some formatting fixes, can you suggest some additional fixes?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Edit pending [peer review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/771128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide $[0,1]$ into $b$ regions of width $b^{-1}$.  Then, in the $k^\text{th}$ region, the first term in the $b$-expansion is $k-1$.  Now, consider
$$
\int_{(k-1)b^{-1}}^{kb^{-1}}f(x)dx.
$$
Now, multiply this by $c$, you get
\begin{align*}
c\int_{(k-1)b^{-1}}^{kb^{-1}}f(x)dx&=\int_{(k-1)b^{-1}}^{kb^{-1}}((k-1)+f(b(x-(k-1)b^{-1})))dx\\
&=\frac{k-1}{b}+\int_{(k-1)b^{-1}}^{kb^{-1}}f(bx-k+1)dx
\end{align*}
Then, using the $u$-substitution $u=bx-k+1$, we get $du=bdx$, the lower limit of the integral is $0$ and the upper limit is $1$.  Therefore,
$$
c\int_{(k-1)b^{-1}}^{kb^{-1}}f(x)dx=\frac{k-1}{b}+\frac{1}{b}\int_0^1f(u)du.
$$

From here, we can proceed as follows:
$$
\int_0^1f(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^{b}\int_{(k-1)b^{-1}}^{kb^{-1}}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{bc}\sum_{k=1}^b\left[(k-1)+\int_0^1f(x)dx\right].
$$
Let $\int_0^1f(x)dx=S$, then
$$
S=\frac{1}{c}S+\frac{b-1}{2c}.
$$
From this, we get that 
$$
S\left(\frac{c-1}{c}\right)=\frac{b-1}{2c}
$$
or that
$$
S=\frac{b-1}{2(c-1)}.
$$
This answer passes the "sanity check" because when $b=c$, then $f(x)=x$ and the area of the triangle determined by $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

The idea behind the first part is that if
$$
x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{b^k}=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\cdots_b
$$
then
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{c^k}=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\cdots_c
$$
Then 
$$
cf(x)=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_{k+1}}{c^k}=a_1.a_2a_3a_4\cdots_c
$$
Observe also that 
$$
bx=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_{k+1}}{b^k}=a_1.a_2a_3a_4\cdots_b
$$
Combining all of this, we see that 
$$
f(bx-a_1)=0.a_2a_3a_4\cdots_c.
$$
Therefore,
$$
cf(x)=a_1+f(bx-a_1).
$$
Since $a_1$ varies between $0$ and $b-1$, every point in the $k$-th interval $((k-1)b^{-1},kb^{-1})$ has $a_1=k-1$.

Comment: But how did you get $c\int_{kb^{-1}}^{(k+1)b^{-1}}f(x)dx=(k-1)+\int_0^1f(x)dx.$

Comment: Look at what happens to the sum $\sum\frac{a_k}{c^k}$ when you multiply by $c$.  You end up with $a_0+\sum\frac{a_{k-1}}{c^k}$, i.e., you've shifted everything to the left (plus a constant).  In addition, by looking at the upper and lower endpoints of the interval, you can see that the entire interval becomes $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Can you explain, please, why the first term is $k-1$ ?

Comment: Ok, another correction, perhaps now everything is correct?